# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ado.net, connection-string

I got this error : "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
in vb.net windows application for sql connection string
here is the code:

```
 Dim sqlcon As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("strcon")
                                                     .ConnectionString)
```

I am getting error for this line

Thanks in advance

Comment: do accept answer if you got the info you want .....

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if there is no connection string named `strcon` in your app.config.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is no connection string in your config with name "strcon"... in case strcon is a variable in your code then you need to remove the "" from the strcon as shown below:

```
Dim sqlcon As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings(strcon).ConnectionString)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this line of the code

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("strcon").ConnectionString
```

its returning value or not / error is coming because this may returning no vlaue i.e null value

one more thing have look to your configuration file and check for the "strcon" name connectionstring i.e it exist or not

also you typed correct spell or not

Answer (score 0):

the connection string: strcon most likely does not exist in your app.config

Answer (score 0):

You would be getting a `Null Reference` Exception Check if you have defined `strcon` as connection string in web.config